# Why does Backbone.Modelbinder only bind the last instance of a list of views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-binding

In a list of items, every item has its' own modelbinder object to bind the models' values.

The problem that I'm having could be reproduced: http://jsfiddle.net/goodafternoon/NmgkY/#base

Only the last element that appears in the list gets bound and thus only the that element responds to the models event listener

```
this.on("change", function() {
    console.log('event');
});
```

I'm using ironcooks famous Modelbinder module : https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

If you had a similar problem, here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goodafternoon/XwT2k/1/

The problem was that I was creating a new instance of the ModelBinder object in the class rather than creating it when the model is instantiated, so there was only ever one ModelBinder, which is why I only ever got the binding on one element.